Can 'of manuals' be fronted in '...the most conservative of manuals...'?

Only the most conservative of manuals still present this rule without qualification.

'conservative' seems to be an adjective, so some nouns may be fused with it: of manuals, only the most conservative [manuals] still present this rule without qualification.
I think this may be similar to 'Of this dozen nouns and names, half are incorrect?'

Sure but why not say: Even the most conservative manual? Rather than your awkward phrasing that sounds like a Bernard Shaw play...

@Lambie Trying to determine the relationship between 'of manuals' and 'the most conservative'.

Yes, Of manuals, only the most conservative ... would be grammatical.
It makes "manuals" the topic, and suggests that you are then going to talk about other kinds of writing, in contrast to manuals.
Note that I have set Of manuals off with a comma. Without a comma I find it odd, and have difficulty finding a plausible context for it.

In English we sometimes put "of" between a superlative adjective and its noun to emphasize the adjective, or simply to make the language sound more formal.
Yes, you could say, "only the most conservative manuals", and the meaning would be the same.
Likewise, you could say, "the fastest cars", or also, "the fastest of cars". "The prettiest girls", or "The prettiest of girls", etc.
Note this is only done with superlatives, the "most" of something. You can say "the greediest of men", but not "the greedy of men".
Side note: Maybe this isn't a source of confusion, but "conservative" here means "adhering to old rules". It is only tangentially related to political conservatism.
